# Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I'm trying to do an upload with Alamofire using this code (where photo.image is a UIImage)

```
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(photo.image, 1.0)

Alamofire.upload(
    multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
        multipartFormData.append(data: imageData!, withName: "unicorn")
    },
    to: "https://httpbin.org/post",
    encodingCompletion: { encodingResult in
        switch encodingResult {
        case .success(let upload, _, _):
            upload.responseJSON { response in
                debugPrint(response)
            }
        case .failure(let encodingError):
            print(encodingError)
        }
    }
)
```

However, this tells me "Expression type '()' is ambiguous without more context.

I am not sure what I'm doing wrong here and would love some advice.

Comment: In which line do you have this problem?

Comment: what Alamofire version is this? I can't find the `to` parameter in any of the upload method overloads

Comment: @MarcoSantarossa: the first one

Comment: @marosoaie: 4.0.0

Comment: I'm getting this same issue. Did you figure this out?

Comment: @sfkaos yes I did. I've added an answer for this question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had the wrong arguments for `multipartFormData`. Here's what worked:

```
multipartFormData: { multipartFormData in
                    multipartFormData.append(imageData!, withName: "photo", fileName: "image.jpg", mimeType: "image/jpg")
                },
```

Comment: Thank you for posting this. Easiest fix ever thanks to your post, from my over 15 billion searches for solutions to stupid Swift cryptic errors. Cheers!